# Creating Laravel Array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm trying to create an array with Laravel but customise some of the values.

For example, if I was to return `$user->rounds` this would return

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "sample name"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "sample name 2"
    }
]
```

I want to customise the return to something like

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "sample name",
        "extra": "Extra Detail"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "sample name 2",
        "extra": "Extra Detail"
    }
]
```

I'm trying to do it, by the following code:

```
$data = array();

foreach ($user->rounds as $r) {
    $data = [
        'id' => $r->id,
        'name' => $r->name,
        'extra' => 'Test Extra'
    ];
}

return $data;
```

But it returns only one round while it should be returning 3.

Comment: You're overwriting `$data` on each loop. I assume you wanted to do `$data[] = ...` notice the extra `[]` after data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add array to `$data` array with each iteration:

```
$data[] = [
    'id' => $r->id,
    'name' => $r->name,
    'extra' => 'Test Extra'
];
```

Also, you could use [`array_push()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) function for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this

```
$data = array();
$i=0;
foreach($user->rounds as $r){
  $data[$i] = [
    'id' => $r->id,
    'name' => $r->name,
    'extra' => 'Test Extra'
  ];
  $i++;
}
return $data;
```